# What does the clrrwi instruction do on PowerPC?

Tags: xbox, powerpc

I need to Reverse these PowerPC instructions here they are:

```
clrrwi    r10, r10, 7
clrrwi    r31, r11, 7
R10 = 64
R11 = b3
```

I dont know the instruction `clrrwi` and i cant find it on the internet.

Comment: You may find reading this thread useful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22238073/confused-with-powerpcs-registerss-values

Comment: I still dont understand

Comment: It's equivalent to writing "r10=r10 & 0xFFFFFF80" and "r31=r11 & 0xFFFFFF80" in C. It could be used to round down to the nearest 128 bit multiple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an expert understanding of the instruction set, but I believe it works as follows:

**clrrwi** is a simplified mnemonic that can be used instead of

```
rlwinm rA, rS, 0, 0, 31 - n.
```

The standard **rlwinm** takes the following form:

```
rlwinm rA, rS, SH, MB, ME
```

n.b. **rlwinm** stands for Rotate Left Word Immediate then aNd with Mask

Where;

- rA = target general-purpose register (where the result is stored)
- rS    = source general-purpose register for operation
- SH = shift amount
- MB = mask begin (start bit for mask)
- ME = mask end (end bit for mask)

With your example;

```
clrrwi    r10, r10, 7
```

- the contents of register r10 are rotated left by 0 bits (no rotation)
- A mask is created; with 1's from bit (0 + 32) to ((31 - 7) + 32) and 0's everywhere else. [32 - 56]
- then r10 (after its rotation of 0 bits) is logically ANDed with this mask
- the result is stored in r10

Most of this can be read from the IBM documentation available at:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/systems/library/es-archguide-v2-pdf.pdf